# Как поменять значение placeholder?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, input, placeholder

В форме есть 2 input, у каждого свой placeholder, они задаются кодом jquery, доступа в html-разметке нет, значения одинаковые. Возможно ли поменять их значения на разные средствами css либо чистого js.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$('.search-city').select2({
        language: "ru",
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        placeholder: "Введите название города",
        selectOnClose: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/city/',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$('.search-city').select2({
        language: "ru",
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        placeholder: "Введите название города",
        selectOnClose: true,
        ajax: {
            url: '/api/city/',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Скорее всего второй `<select>` имеет у себя класс, например, `to` (так как на скриншоте видно, что у первого есть класс `from`). Тогда просто уточняем селекторы и делаем индивидуальную привязку с разными параметрами:

```js
$('.search-city.from').select2({
  ...
  placeholder: "Введите название города, откуда уезжаете",
  ...
});

$('.search-city.to').select2({
  ...
  placeholder: "Введите название города, куда хотите поехать",
  ...
});
```

Comment: Да, это сработало, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

у  тебя в JQuery строка  `placeholder: "Введите название города",` то и является твоим placeholder`om

Comment: да, но проблема в том что она задает одновременно одинаковые значения для двух инпутов с классами .select2а мне нужно чтобы они были разными.